How do i get a new poetry line to be hanging indented .25 inches yet in a custom blockquote format ,5 inches away from margins?
Im trying to get this doc environment which has everything in a blockquote form without hanging indentation and that will be used in a double spaced doc to get the functionality of a picture:
\NewDocumentEnvironment{poetry}{}{%
  \list{}{\leftmargin 0.5in}
  \item[]
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
  \vspace{-\topsep}
}{%
  \endlist
  \vspace{-\topsep}
}

I am aware that the following  not poetry but I needed to test with something and I am wondering how to make it so that if I have something like this
\begin{poetry}
    There are lots of examples of good teamwork in theatre. Broadway shows like "Hamilton" by Lin-Manuel Miranda show how great collaboration can be. \\
    Miranda's writing and music, along with Thomas Kail's direction and Andy Blankenbuehler's choreography, created an amazing musical (Gillette, 2009). \\
    The Royal Shakespeare Company's adaptations of Shakespeare's plays show how teamwork can make old plays feel new again. Community and experimental theatres also rely a lot on teamwork, bringing different people together to make unique and powerful shows (Roznowski and Domer, 2016).
\end{poetry}

I get this

It would be of great help if anyone could help me with this.
general document code:
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, BoldFont=Timesbd.ttf, ItalicFont=Timesi.ttf, BoldItalicFont=Timesbi.ttf]{Times.ttf}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \doublespacing
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lua-ul}
\usepackage[leftmargin=1in, rightmargin=0in, vskip=0in]{quoting}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %Fancy-header package to modify header/page numbering (insert last name)
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \lhead{} 
    \chead{} 
    \rhead{Blub \thepage} 
    \lfoot{} 
    \cfoot{} 
    \rfoot{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 
%To make sure we actually have header 0.5in away from top edge
%12pt is one-sixth of an inch. Subtract this from 0.5in to get headsep value
\setlength{\headsep}{.3333pt} % Set headsep to ensure total distance from top edge is 0.5 inches

\newcommand{\bibent}{\noindent \hangindent 40pt}
\newenvironment{workscited}{\newpage {\centering Works Cited\par}}{\newpage }

\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{{\noindent\textbf{#1}\par}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{{\noindent\textit{#1}\par}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}}

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{{\noindent\centering\textbf{#1}\par}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}}

\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{{\noindent\centering\textit{#1}\par}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}}

\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\refstepcounter{subparagraph}{\noindent\underLine{#1}\par}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}}

\RaggedRight

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{blockquote}{}{%
  \list{}{\leftmargin 0.5in}
  \item[]
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
  \vspace{-\topsep}
}{%
  \endlist
  \vspace{-\topsep}
}

\makeatletter
% Define custom commands for instructor and course
\NewDocumentCommand{\instructor}{m}{\def\@instructor{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\course}{m}{\def\@course{#1}}

% Renew the maketitle command
\RenewDocumentCommand{\maketitle}{}{
    \noindent \@author\\
    \@instructor\\
    \@course\\
    \@date\\
    {\centering{\@title}\par}\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}}
\makeatother

% Set author, instructor, course, date, and title in the preamble
\author{Author}
\instructor{Instructor's Name}
\course{Course Name}
\date{\today}
\title{Your Paper Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\begin{poetry}
    There are lots of examples of good teamwork in theatre. Broadway shows like "Hamilton" by Lin-Manuel Miranda show how great collaboration can be. \\
    Miranda's writing and music, along with Thomas Kail's direction and Andy Blankenbuehler's choreography, created an amazing musical (Gillette, 2009). \\
    The Royal Shakespeare Company's adaptations of Shakespeare's plays show how teamwork can make old plays feel new again. Community and experimental theatres also rely a lot on teamwork, bringing different people together to make unique and powerful shows (Roznowski and Domer, 2016).
\end{poetry}

\begin{workscited}
  
\end{workscited}

\end{document}


You want to set a left margin of 0.75in, with a parindent of -0.25in. However, due to the overall settings of ragged2e, you need a blank line to separate poetry lines rather than \\.
The code below shows an edited version of your code. I'll explain after the code and the picture.
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[base]{babel}% avoid annoying warning about lipsum

\usepackage[
  margin=1in,
  headheight=14.5pt,
  headsep=0.3333in,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lua-ul}
\usepackage[leftmargin=1in, rightmargin=0in, vskip=0in]{quoting}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %Fancy-header package to modify header/page numbering (insert last name)
\usepackage{hyperref}


%%% FONTS
% I don't have this font
%\setmainfont{Times.ttf}[
%  Ligatures=TeX,
%  BoldFont=Timesbd.ttf,
%  ItalicFont=Timesi.ttf,
%  BoldItalicFont=Timesbi.ttf
%]
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

%%% HEAD AND FOOT
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Blub \thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 

%%% COMMANDS AND ENVIRONMENTS
\newcommand{\bibent}{\noindent \hangindent 40pt}

\newenvironment{workscited}{\newpage {\centering Works Cited\par}}{\newpage }

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{{\noindent\textbf{#1}\par}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{{\noindent\textit{#1}\par}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}}

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{{\noindent\centering\textbf{#1}\par}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}}

\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{{\noindent\centering\textit{#1}\par}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}}

\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\refstepcounter{subparagraph}{\noindent\underLine{#1}\par}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{blockquote}{}{%
  \list{}{\leftmargin 0.5in}
  \item[]
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
  \vspace{-\topsep}
}{%
  \endlist
  \vspace{-\topsep}
}

\makeatletter
% Define custom commands for instructor and course
\NewDocumentCommand{\instructor}{m}{\def\@instructor{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\course}{m}{\def\@course{#1}}

% Renew the maketitle command
\RenewDocumentCommand{\maketitle}{}{
    \noindent \@author\\
    \@instructor\\
    \@course\\
    \@date\\
    {\centering{\@title}\par}\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentEnvironment{poetry}{}{%
  \list{}{%
    \leftmargin=0.75in
    \topsep=0pt
    \listparindent=-0.25in
    \itemindent=-0.25in
    \parsep=0pt
    \partopsep=0pt
  }
  \item[]
}{%
  \endlist
}

%%% final settings
\RaggedRight
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
%\doublespacing


%%% METADATA
% Set author, instructor, course, date, and title in the preamble
\author{Author}
\instructor{Instructor's Name}
\course{Course Name}
\date{\today}
\title{Your Paper Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\begin{poetry}
    There are lots of examples of good teamwork in theatre. Broadway shows 
    like "Hamilton" by Lin-Manuel Miranda show how great collaboration can be.

    Miranda's writing and music, along with Thomas Kail's direction and Andy
    Blankenbuehler's choreography, created an amazing musical (Gillette, 2009).

    The Royal Shakespeare Company's adaptations of Shakespeare's plays show how
    teamwork can make old plays feel new again. Community and experimental
    theatres also rely a lot on teamwork, bringing different people together to
    make unique and powerful shows (Roznowski and Domer, 2016).
\end{poetry}

\end{document}


Points to note

I'd not mix package loading and settings
\headsep should be set with geometry
It's really unclear why stating \setlength{\parindent}{0.5in} over and over again
The redefinition of the sectioning commands have been kept, but they're completely wrong, because you almost certainly will end up with a title at the bottom of the page; use titlesec instead
As usual, hyperref should be loaded last (you're loading none of the exceptions to this rule)

Finally, I commented \doublespacing for two reasons: first, the effects of the code are better visible; second, \doublespacing should never be used.

hello! i made a new version of the doc which includes your solution: https://pastebin.com/bygvktkH and this makes edits that you suggested. though, two questions: When you siad don't ever use \doublespacing what about when I'm using this for MLA which calls for doublespacing? and when said to use titlesec instead do i only redefine sections that way? or do i turn the maketitle and the redefinition of sections into titlesec code? how exactly would you do this?
